# Cello A5 possible?

Tags: cello, instrument-range

I am working on a composition of mine. When I transposed an already high section on the Cello to a different key it ended up having an A5 in it.

Is this possible to play for a good Cello player?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy to play A5 (or, indeed, even A6) on cello *as a natural flageolett*. However (even if the airy sound of a flageolett is ok for your application), it won't help with any tones merely *close to* A5. So if that's just the very tip of a melodic line, you'll need to think of a position where also the other notes are feasible as non-flageoletts. The 11th position might be suitable, it has the thumb resting nicely on the third harmonic (A4 on the D string) and the A5 sitting quite reachable for the 3rd finger. This position works well for the keys of G to A; for ♭-keys it's not so nice (for instance the F5 lies uncomfortably close to the thumb).

So – it is certainly possible, though how well it can work out depends on the exact context. In general, please try to think about *how* passages can be played, not just *if it's possible*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is on the very top of the cello's range but it's possible. I would not write a lot that high in their range and if possible I would transpose that part down slightly.

The picture bellow shows you the typical range of the cello:

[image]

Comment: @NicolasAntor I agree with Dom that this is starting to be at the highest I would ever regularly write for cello. Actually, I start getting nervous, as a player, when it gets to C5 or D5. However, I've played pieces that even go as high as A6, the context matters a huge amount. If the line is mostly stepwise and takes its time approaching A5, or, alternatively, if I can go straight from A4 to A5 (and thus hear the octave leap as a glide up), then it isn't a particularly big deal at all. If I'm consistently in that range, but jumping all over the place it's extremely difficult.

Comment: Also, as @leftaroundabout points out, it's quite easy as a natural harmonic (normally produced by lightly touching the string at the position of D4 on the A-string).

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick answers. Acctually I wrote the composition for a team which has a pretty skilled Cello Player. I really just wasn't sure if it is physically possible to do so, because Sibelius marked the Note as red ;)

Comment: @NicolasAntor: Sibelius is apparently not to be trusted with deciding what's playable and what's not! Really, the absolute pitch of a single note is almost completely irrelevant to this.